# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select to my database and I set the date like this

```
$endDate = new DateTime($fetch['loan_end']);
$endDate->add(new DateInterval('P5D'));
```

executed here:

```
$stmtBal = $controller->runQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) 
                                      FROM tbl_paid
                                      WHERE pay_date <= :endDate 
                                      AND (c_id=:c_id AND (transaction_num=:transaction_num))");
    $stmtBal->execute(array(":endDate"         =>  $endDate, 
                            ":c_id"            =>  $get_id,
                            ":transaction_num" =>  $fetch['transaction_num']));
```

And then the xampp gave me this error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in ......... etc

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
$stmtBal->execute(array(":endDate"=>$fetch['loan_end'], ":c_id"=>$get_id, ":transaction_num"=>$fetch['transaction_num']));
```